# An inequality with n variables

Tags: inequality

I am not sure if this inequality is correct

$n.x_1.x_2...x_n+(n-1).\sum_{sym}x_i^n\geq{\sum_{sym}x_1^{n-1}x_2}$

it comes from the proof problem

$\frac{n}{a_1+...+a_n}+\frac{n-1}{n}.\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_i}\geq{\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n-1)a_i+a_j}}$

The problem wants to be proved by integral, so I bring back the inequality presented above.if we consider n=2 then we have equality happens.if we consider n=3 we have schur inequality

I have tried to proof with n variables but it is really hard and
I don't think I.G.I can help, it's impossible :))

i really don't have any ideas anyone can give their opinion.thanks

Comment: For $n=3$ is it $\frac{3}{a+b+c}+\frac{2}{3}\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{a}\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{2a+b}+\frac{1}{2b+a}+\frac{1}{3a}\right)$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yes :D i thinks it is hard if we don't use integral

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg For example, the problem of gabriel dospinesscu:$\sum_{sym}\frac{1}{4a}+\sum_{sym}\frac{1}{a+b}\geq{\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{3a+b}}$. Solution by integral is very beautiful

Comment: I just want to understand your notation. I understood that you want to use the harazi's integral method.

Comment: I see. It's just the Vasc's inequality. ;)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://rgmia.org/papers/v8n2/M4.pdf

I hope, it will help.

Comment: thanks you so much

Comment: @Question You are welcome!